# Reading date-time data stored as Excel format into MATLAB

Tags: excel, matlab, datetime, loaddata

I have a csv file which contains a column for data-time in Excel format, and two other columns which are floats; The Excel format date includes the number of days since 01-Jan-1900, so for example, 2 means 02-Jan-1900, and 365 means 30-Dec-1900, and so on.

The file looks like the following:

```
date,temp,value
41909.89,49.67,32
41910.67,49.16,36
41911.37,45.33,37
```

What is the best way to read this file and convert the date to datetime format in MATLAB?

Comment: Did you already google "Excel date Matlab" ?  The first hit (for me anyway) is from the Mathworks site and explains exactly what you need to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `readtable` to read the file, then convert the dates using `datetime`.  If you have the Financial Toolbox then you can do the conversion from Excel date numbers to MATLAB date numbers using `x2mdate`.  If not then the offset is dependent on the date format you are using in Excel.  See the doc for [x2mdate](https://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/x2mdate.html) for details of possible offsets.

```
>> tbl = readtable('datafile.txt')
tbl =
  3×3 table
      date      temp     value
    ________    _____    _____
    41909.89    49.67    32   
    41910.67    49.16    36   
    41911.37    45.33    37   
>> tbl.date = datetime(tbl.date+693960,'ConvertFrom','Datenum')
tbl =
  3×3 table
            date            temp     value
    ____________________    _____    _____
    27-Sep-2014 21:21:36    49.67    32   
    28-Sep-2014 16:04:48    49.16    36   
    29-Sep-2014 08:52:48    45.33    37
```